# Disable PDF/CSV Output Formats on report level in SSRS 2005

Tags: reporting-services

I am wondering if there is a way to disable certain output types for SSRS on a report by report basis. I am aware of the way to do it with all reports in the rsreportserver.config file, but this is not what I want.

[This Post](http://sqlserver-indo.org/blogs/mca/archive/2009/03/08/disable-pdf-export-in-reporting-services.aspx) mentioned something about doing it with a query string, but didn't say anything past that. I cannot find anything that explains how to do this.

Comment: As far as I know this is done only globally in rsreportserver.config

Comment: Still true in 2008 even: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/451f39bc-1ebf-4f55-9b38-0bca919ad3af/